# C# Tool disappears from the design

Tags: c#, listview

I have a ListView that just disappeared from the design page of my `Form1`. I have not deleted it or touched anything regarding `ListView`'s code. I was actually working on my `MessageBox`. Actually, I have another

I have had this happen to me before and it got fixed by clicking `Ctrl+Z` (Undo), but that doesn't help now.

A little bit of research showed me that this is a known bug from VS2010, but I am using VS2012. Windows 7 x64.

Using `listView1.Show();` in the code *does* show the `ListView` after I start the debugging, but if I want to edit it in the designing I have no way to access its properties (other than the code).

Comment: Did you try to select the control in the dropdown that appears in the property window (above the list of properties)? Is it appearing in that dropdown?

Comment: @sallushan, yes it is. If I doubleclick I can see the code where the properties are defined

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround you can try is,

1. Select the control in the DropDown of Property Window
2. Press ESC key
3. Press Ctrl+X
4. Press Ctrl+V

When press ESC key, Visual Studio moves focus from property window to form designer. At this point control is still selected you can see it in the dropdown of property window. Then when you press Ctrl+X you actually Cuts it, and then on pressing Ctrl+V you paste it again on form. Which causes the control to be added on form again.

I hope it may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

A small workaround I found - delete the form from the form design (the place with the tools in the sidebar) - this will get rid of any code you have in the designer.cs file. After that just type in and create everything from scratch.

If you have an old element with ton of properties that disappears after you do something, but you can still restore with `Ctrl+Z` you can try to `Copy` its code from the `designer.cs` file  and then `Paste` in the `Form1.cs` file and changing it according to your needs.

Yes, it sucks, but it's the only solution I managed to come up with.